# tkinter buttons don't open all batch files

Tags: python, batch-file, tkinter, popen

I have a project at work and our real developers don't have time for what I need so I am creating my first GUI.

It has two buttons. When clicked they run a batch file. The batch file runs a registry file, and it runs the software executable. It works fine when I was testing, but that .bat only ran an echo saying "Hello World!"... When I replace that batch file with the batch below:

```
start /d "C:\Cogent\cls.chd\" cls.reg

SLEEP 5

start /d "C:\Cogent\cls.chd\bin\" CLSMain.exe
```

I run the same .py file and I get the following error:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python33\lib\subprocess.py", line 1112, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python33\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1475, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\A32DZZZ\Desktop\LivescanMonrowFinal.py", line 31, in run1
    process=subprocess.Popen("launch.bat", cwd=r"C:\\Cogent\\cls.chd")
  File "C:\Python33\lib\subprocess.py", line 824, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\subprocess.py", line 1118, in _execute_child
    raise WindowsError(*e.args)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified"
```

Can anyone tell me what I am apparently not understanding? My GUI is below:

```
from tkinter import *
import subprocess

master = Tk()
master.title("Monroe Livescan Version Selector")
master.geometry("400x166")

#Menu construction
menubar=Menu(master)
filemenu = Menu(menubar,tearoff = 0)
filemenu.add_command(label="Close")
menubar.add_cascade(label="File",menu=filemenu)

helpmenu = Menu(menubar,tearoff = 0)
helpmenu.add_command(label="Help Docs")
helpmenu.add_command(label="About")
menubar.add_cascade(label="Help",menu=helpmenu)

master.config(menu=menubar)

#Define run function for first Livescan package.
def run1():
    process=subprocess.Popen("launch.bat", cwd=r"C:\\Cogent\\cls.chd")

def run2():
    process=subprocess.Popen("launch.bat", cwd=r"C:\\Cogent\\cls.iafis")

#Define the button geometry and commands to run.    
b1 = Button(master, text='Child ID', command=run1)
b1.pack(padx=5, pady=5)
b1.config(height=4, width=45)
b2 = Button(master, text='IAFIS', command=run2)
b2.pack(padx=5, pady=5)
b2.config(height=4, width=45)


mainloop()
```

Comment: Why do you think this is a `tkinter` problem? What happens if you run `subprocess` directly?

Comment: Looks like pretty much the same error. I don't think it's specific to tkinter, the buttons work and the gui is fine. I guess the subprocess command has something wrong with it but I don't know enough to tell exactly what it is.

Comment: In that case, you can probably strip out everything GUI-related. Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: The error is telling you it can't find the file Have you tried putting in a fully qualified path? Probably you're simply not in the folder that has the file when you run the script.

Comment: So I read the blog posted by jon and was able to solve my issue. Tkinter was correct and my subprocess was fine, all I had to do was move the .py in a folder with the .reg and .bat files and it worked  fine. Ended up changing the start <reg file> in batch to just using regedit /S as well... thanks all.

Answer (score 0):

So I read the blog posted by jon and was able to solve my issue. Tkinter was correct and my subprocess was fine, all I had to do was move the .py in a folder with the .reg and .bat files and it worked. Ended up changing the start  in batch to just using regedit /S as well... thanks all.